# Is there a pandas function to merge 2 dfs so that repeating items in the second df are added as columns to the first df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I have a hard time to formulate this problem in abstract terms, therefore I will mostly try to explain it with examples.

I have 2 pandas dataframes (I get them from a sqlite DB).

First DF:
[image]

Second DF:
[image]

So the thing is: There are several images per "capture". I would like to add the images to the capture df as columns, so that each capture has 9 image columns, each with a path. There are always 9 images per capture.

I solved it in pandas with what I know in the following way:

```
cam_idxs = sorted(list(range(9)) * 2)
for cam_idx in cam_idxs:
    sub_df = images.loc[(images["camera_id"]==cam_idx)]
    captures = captures.merge(sub_df[["image", "capture_id"]], left_on="id", 
                              right_on="capture_id")
```

I imagine though that there must be a better way. At least I imagine people probably stumble into this problem more often when getting data from a sql database.

Since I am getting the data into pandas from a sql database, I am also open to SQL commands that get me this result. And I'm also grateful for people telling me what this kind of operation is called, I did not find a good way to google for this, therefore I am asking here. Excuse me when this question was asked somewhere, I did not find anything with my searchterms.

So the question at the end is: Is there a better way to do this, especially a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: can the downvoters please elaborate? I don't know what to make of the downvote

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the pivot table.

You just need to create a column containing the index of the number of image by capture_id that you will use as columns in the pivot table.

For example this could be :

```py
images['column_pivot'] = [x for x in range(1,10)]*int(images.shape[0]/9)
```

In your case 'column_pivot' would be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...7,8,9] (e.g. rolling from 1 to 9)

Then you pivot :

```py
pd.pivot_table(images, columns='column_pivot', index='capture_id', values='image')
```

This will give the expected result.

Comment: Still need to verify, but just the pivot table is exactly what I was looking for as a term! Thanks!